# How do I use the jQuery Multi module?

Tags: javascript

I have a site theme that needs to use Jquery 2.1.3. The theme uses [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and affects the `node/add` form. So I also need Drupal's default Jquery 1.4 to be running, otherwise the default Drupal scripts on the `node/add` form will not work.

The [Jquery Multi](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti) module is supposed to be the best way of doing this. But how do you use the module? I have installed it and verified that the Jquery 2.1 library is running.

The [Read Me](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jqmulti/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x) file says:

> For instance, if you're loading jQuery 1.7.1, the alias will be jq171, and you can use it in your scripts by wrapping your code as follows:
>
> ```js
> (function($) {
>   // The using jQuery 1.7.1
> })(jq171)
> ```
>
> NOTE: All jQuery targeted to use jQuery Multi (using methods A, B,
> or C above) must properly use a closure around the jQuery code, as is best practice for all Drupal jQuery code, i.e.:
>
> ```js
> (function($) {
>   // The code using jQuery 1.7.1
> })(jQuery)
> ```

Do I wrap my code in both jq213 and Jquery?

```js
(function($) {
    (function($) {
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function() {
          
            /* *********************** */
            /* Mobile only Hamburger menu       */
            /* *********************** */
            $(".masthead .menu").on("click", function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('menu-close');
                $("body").toggleClass('menu-open');
                $(".masthead ul").toggleClass("animated bounceInDown");
                $(".masthead .tap-back").toggle();
           });
                  });
    })(jq213)
})(jQuery);
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work. When I check the HTML source I can see that Jquery 2.1.3 doesn't load, so presumably I am wrapping my scripts wrongly.

In admin/config/system/jqmulti, I can see that Jquery 2.1.3 has been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you did double code wrap?
Try to use:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /* *********************** */
        /* Mobile only Hamburger menu       */
        /* *********************** */
        $(".masthead .menu").on("click", function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-close');
            $("body").toggleClass('menu-open');
            $(".masthead ul").toggleClass("animated bounceInDown");
            $(".masthead .tap-back").toggle();
       });
              });
})(jq213);
```